# Fazer delete de rows em diversas tabelas de forma dinâmica, no Postgres

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, delete

Preciso de fazer um delete para limpar a base de dados de forma automática em tabelas que estão dentro de schemas diferentes, o "public" e o "cine";

Tenho a seguinte query que me devolve

```
SELECT concat('"',table_schema,'"', '.', '"',table_name, '"') as 
      table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public' OR table_schema = 'cine' AND 
column_name = 'cine_uuid'
GROUP BY table_name, table_schema;
```

Esta, devolve-me todos os schemas e tabelas que teem como coluna "cine_uuid".
É possivel fazer um delete da seguinte forma:

```
DELETE FROM [TABELAS] WHERE cine_uuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

O que pretendia era que a partir de uma query, fazer um delete nas diversas tabelas nos diversos schemas.

É possível?

Comment: Cláudio, não tem como em uma só `QUERY` você excluir o registro de duas Tabelas, você precisaria excluir o registro uma a uma. O máximo que da para fazer era se em uma das tabelas você conseguisse fazer um `DELETE CASCADE`, mas ai uma tabela deveria ter um relacionamento (`FK`) com a outra.

Comment: acredito que tenha como fazer com plsql, vou tentar fazer. Quando precisei fiz em C#, mais fácil pra mim, e era usando um truncate, então nao se aplica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz a seguinte função:

Seleciona todas as tabelas, dos schemas informados, que contém a coluna informada, e percorre executando o delete:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_from_tables (id varchar 
)
RETURNS pg_catalog.void AS
$body$
    declare
       temprow record;
       begin

       FOR temprow IN
        (select 
            t.table_name
            from information_schema.tables t
            inner join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name and c.column_name = 'cine_uuid '
            where t.table_schema in ('public','cine'))
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM '|| temprow.table_name || ' where cine_uuid = ''' || $1 || ''''; 
    END LOOP;

       end;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

**Utilização:**

```
select delete_from_tables('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::varchar);
```